# Using conditional urls during $http POST requests of angularjs service calls in ASP.Net Web API2

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am sending requests in the following way right now.

In PROD(hosted in local IIS server) -

```
this.post = function (Prescription) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/SmileMakersApp/SmileMakersApp/api/PrescriptionsAPI",
        data: Prescription
    });
    return request;
}
```

IN DEV -

```
this.post = function (Prescription) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/api/PrescriptionsAPI",
        data: Prescription
    });
    return request;
}
```

The problem is I am maintaining version and regularly updating my code through git. So whenever I make new changes to this file I have to resolve conflicts each time. And there are many similar requests like this and resolving conflicts for each of them is cumbersome. Is there any way so that I can define different urls in PROD and DEV? I have already done something like this in back-end.

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
{
    <base href="/">
}
else
{
    <base href="/SmileMakersApp/SmileMakersApp/">
}
```

Comment: You can use the same base href value in angular: document.querySelector('head > base').getAttribute('href').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is to configure different environments, like development, stage and production. Since you are using Angular you should have a look at a plugin called [angular-environement](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-environment).

Once installed, add `environment` as a dependency and set up the domains and variables for each environment as needed.

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['environment']).
  config(function(envServiceProvider) {

  // this is where you need to set the domains and variables for each   environment 
  envServiceProvider.config({
    domains: {
      development: ['localhost', 'dev.local'],
      production: ['acme.com', 'acme.net', 'acme.org']
  },

  vars: {
    development: {
      apiUrl: '//localhost/api',
      staticUrl: '//localhost/static'
    },

    production: {
      apiUrl: '//api.acme.com/v2',
      staticUrl: '//static.acme.com'
    }               
  }
});

    // run the environment check, so the comparison is made 
    // before controllers and services are built 
    envServiceProvider.check();
});
```

Once set up, you need to inject `envService` into you controller. You can then access your urls, variables etc.

```
controller('SomeController', ['$scope', 'envService', function($scope, envService) {
    // gets the current environemt
    var environment = envService.get(); 

    // sets the desired environment
    envService.set('production');

    // gets the desired environment variable.
    var apiUrl = envService.read('apiUrl');
}]);
```

Note that this code has not actually been tested, but should give you an outline how to implement it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I will try this out and let you know after reaching home. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but couldn't check yet, I'm in a huge workload at this moment and need to check during weekend. If everything works out, I will make sure to accept it as answer and give an up vote too as first thing during weekend.

Comment: implemented and worked flawlessly. Thumbs up and thanks!